# How to enable network extension via terminal command on macOS

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions

I'm managing a Sentinel One tenant in my company.
As part of the installation process, the user is required to enable a few settings:

1. Full disk access
2. Network Extension.

The problem is that the users keep missing this after installation and I would like to do it myself remotely.

I want to enable this with a command in a remote shell operation in S1 console.

Does anyone know if this is possible?